# Python Selenium Scraping HREF + Anchor Text

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have the following snippet that is successful in extracting the anchor text and the href attribute from the xpath that I didn't disclose. With both of the retrieved values, I would like them to match up so I can write to a file. You can see my thought process in the last couple of lines.

```
deal_title = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//")
for title in deal_title:
    anchor_title = title.text

deal_link = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//")
for link in deal_link:
    text_link = link.get_attribute('href')

#code below does not work

for text_link, anchor_title in zip(text_link, anchor_title):
    f.write("<a href=" + text_link + ">" + anchor_title + "</a>")
```

Ultimately this should print out all of the anchor texts (no markup) with the correct corresponding URL, that results in a clickable link in the HTML file I'm writing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing all values in single variable. You will get the last value always. I am storing it in list. So that, you can iterate over the list as given below. It may solve your issue.

```
deal_title = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//")
titles = []
for title in deal_title:
    titles.append(title.text)

deal_link = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//")
links = []
for link in deal_link:
    links.append(link.get_attribute('href'))

for title, link in zip(titles, links):
    f.write("<a href=" + link + ">" + title + "</a>")
```

Comment: Thank you. That definitely got me closer. This actually output a hyperlinked URL instead of a hyperlinked anchor text which is why I am using the title variable to scrape the anchor text. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, it is my mistake. Updated the answer. Please check now.

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfectly!